# What explosives work best with water?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, pressure, water, explosions

What explosives work best with water? 
For Example:
If there was an olympic pool and I dropped some explosive into it.
 
With which explosive type would detonation velocity and pressure be most effective at lifting the water out of the pool?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not serious, to put it mildly.

Comment: Didn't know explosive properties in water were off topic Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I edited it to make it a little more clear.

Comment: If you want to empty the pool, why not not use a pump? You probably can procure one and use it to empty the pool in less time than it would take a demolition expert to figure out how to achieve a satisfactory result using pyrotechnics or high explosives. (Maybe a _lot_ less time,... as in, less than forever.)

Comment: The quickest way of course is to get a sphere of weapons grade plutonium which is 2/3 critical mass.  Throw it into the pool, and in water it will be well above the critical mass.  The water in the pool as well as some of the surrounding area will vaporize and your problem will be solved except that you will not be able to approach the area for centuries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no proper answer, since it depends on (1) properties of the pool walls that are not stated, and (2) properties of the explosive.

But mostly, any force that can move 3750+ cubic meters (i.e. 3750 tons) of water out of a pool with a single push is very likely to break mere concrete.